# How can I declare a function like this in rust trait

Tags: rust

for example. need a global object and determine the object at runtime

```cpp
class A{
};

A* a = nullptr;


// B inherit from A
void Import(B* b){
    a = b;
}
```

I have tried using the Dyn but must Determine the type

```rust
static mut instance: &dyn plugin::BasePlugin;
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^help: provide a definition for the static: `= <expr>;`
```

Comment: That's an antipattern in general. I would rather have a local object `let mut instance: Box<dyn plugin::BasePlugin>` that would serve as a "context", that I pass as an argument to my functions

Comment: What the error message is telling you is that a static variable can't be unset, so you need to give it an initial value. Since a reference can't be null, the closest you can go is to use an `Option` with: `static mut instance: Option<&dyn plugin::BasePlugin> = None;` although as @AlexeyLarionov said global mutable variables are a bad pattern (in any language), which is why Rust makes them very hard to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `static mut`. It's an unsafe-by-design construct meant for low-level code, not normal users who just want a global variable.

Rust assumes single-threaded programs don't exist, so every global variable *must* be thread-safe. Therefore, to mutate it you will have to use a `Mutex` or some other thread-safety alternative like [`ArcSwap`](https://lib.rs/arc_swap). You will need [`lazy_static`](https://lib.rs/crates/lazy_static) to initialize these types.

You won't be able to use just any temporary scope-limited reference in a global variable. `&` is not a general-purpose way to refer to objects in Rust. Consider using `Box<dyn BasePlugin>` or `Arc<dyn BasePlugin>` instead. These allow holding objects by reference without scoped lifetime limitations.

You could use a `&'static` reference, but in practice that would require leaking heap memory. If you plan to set the variable once, it would be okay. If you plan to set it more than once, that's not elegant, and may become problematic.

And finally, consider not using global variables at all. Create objects you need stored in local variables (even as early as in `main()`), and pass them down as arguments to functions that need them. You could make a `struct App` and put data you need as fields of that struct.